# Synonymize [asn.1] and [asn1] tags?

Tags: support, tag-synonym-process

The tags [asn.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asn.1) and [asn1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asn1) both refer to [Abstract Syntax Notation One (ASN.1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1):

[asn.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asn.1) has currently 616 questions and the wiki excerpt reads

> ASN.1 stands for Abstract Syntax Notation One. It is a data
> specification language and a set of encoding rules for serializing the
> data.

[asn1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asn1) has currently 63 questions and its wiki excerpt reads

> Synonymous to "asn.1" tag.

Usage also makes clear that the tags are actual synonyms ([9 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asn.1+asn1) even have both tags) as [asn1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asn1) is used when it's about ASN.1 or one of the respective libraries as far as I can see.

I propose that [asn.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asn.1) becomes the **main tag** since this is also the official abbreviation and has the most questions:

[asn.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asn.1) ← [asn1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asn1)

[Merging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204248) these tags might also be considered.

---

The respective libraries etc. tags seem fine, though, since they use their official names: [pyasn1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyasn1), [asn1crypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asn1crypto), [asn1tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asn1tools) and [phpasn1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpasn1).

Comment: With only 63 Qs with the `asn1`, maybe a manual edit/removal/replacement would be acceptable?

Comment: 63 > 50 so I guess no @AdrianMole (based on what we accept for burnination requests)

Comment: @rene Ah! I must have unknowingly been set to octal mode this morning.

Comment: Merging seems to be appropriate. I don't think we want [[tag:asn1]] to show up again. If something *else* shows up that's different, we'd want to distinguish these tags more.